# How to build a binary tree based on morse code for a random set of letters?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I need to build a binary tree based on a random set of letters... That is, for example for the following combination of letters:

```
A .
C -
R .-
T ..
! -.
```

Must produce the following tree

```
       *
     /   \
    A     C
   / \   /
  T   R !
```

That is, for each node of the tree the letter on the left must be inserted to represent the point "." and right to represent a dash "−"

I wrote the following code but it's incomplete... I don't actually know how to implement the recursion

```
class BinaryTree:
  def __init__(self, key):
    self.dado = key
    self.esq = None
    self.dir = None

def parse_tree(root, letter):
  if alphabet[letter] == '.':
    root.esq = BinaryTree(letter)
  elif alphabet[letter] == '-':
    root.dir = BinaryTree(letter)


N = int(input())
alphabet = {}

tree = BinaryTree('*')
for n in range(N):
  letter, morse_code = input().split()
  alphabet[letter] = morse_code
  parse_tree(tree, letter)
```

For the following data sample

```
5
A .
C -
R .-
T ..
! -.
```

However it is needed to pay attention to that if we have a node for which there is not a letter we should then include * as you can see in the following example

```
A .-.
E ..
I ...
T -.
M --.
N -..
```

It should then produce the following tree:

[image: * * * E * T * I * A * N * M *]

Comment: Why is it tagged with recursion?

Comment: @pavel, because I think that it may need some recursive function to build the tree or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your recursion, you continue to call the function until the path string (the set of `.`s and `_`s) is exhausted for a given node:

```
class BinaryTree:
   def __init__(self, key = None):
      self.head = key
      self.left = None
      self.right = None

def add_node(tree, node, path):
   if not path:
      tree.head = node
   else:
      if getattr(tree, (p:='left' if path[0] == '.' else 'right')) is None:
          setattr(tree, p, BinaryTree('*')) #default character for empty node
      add_node(getattr(tree, p), node, path[1:])

s = """
A .
C -
R .-
T ..
! -.
"""
t = BinaryTree('*') #root node of tree
for i in filter(None, s.split('\n')):
   add_node(t, *i.split())
```

Comment: Hey, @Ajax1234... I have written some more requirements... Can you explain me how to handle that?

Comment: @LucasBrenodeSouzaNoronhaB Please see my recent edit.